# Include headers with a library in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

My project has two utility library in it. I am looking for the best way to write CMake configurations for the libraries.

```
/my_project
 --> CMakeLists.txt
 --> main.cpp
 --> /utils
      --> CMakeLists.txt
      --> common.h
      --> /base_c
           --> CMakeLists.txt
           --> base_c.c
           --> base_c.h
      --> /base_cpp
           --> CMakeLists.txt
           --> base_cpp.cpp
           --> base_cpp.hpp
```

My current CMake files:

/my_project/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_requared(VERSION 3.8)
project(my_project)

add_subdirectory(utils)

add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(main utils base_c base_cpp)
```

/my_project/utils/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(base_c)
add_subdirectory(base_cpp)

add_library(utils)
target_sources(utils PUBLIC common.h)
```

/my_project/utils/base_c/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(base_c base_c.c)
target_sources(base_c PUBLIC base_c.h)
```

/my_project/utils/base_cpp/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(base_cpp base_cpp.cpp)
target_sources(base_cpp PUBLIC base_cpp.hpp)

find_library(BASEC base_c ../base_c)
target_link_libraries(base_cpp BASEC)
```

The problem is that `base_cpp` does not find includes from `base_c`. How should I fix the configuration?

I managed to make it work with `target_include_directories(base_cpp PRIVATE ../base_c)`, but that's ugly and shouldn't be necessary, according to [INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#interface-include-directories).

Comment: How documentation for INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES implies that `target_include_directories` is not needed? I am curious how you have managed to compile even single library without `include_directories` or `target_include_directories`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I may be totally wrong on this. Could you explain how I can use `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` of a library?

Comment: Which build system do you use after CMake? Makefiles? Visual Studio projects? Can you examine those files which directories are actually passed as include-directories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Anedar mentioned, to resolve this situation one needs `target_include_directories` with `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` options in the library `CMakeLists.txt`. That populates `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` of the library target, which is used by `target_link_libraries` on the consuming side.

My working configuration:

/my_project/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_requared(VERSION 3.8)
project(my_project)

add_subdirectory(utils)

add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(main utils base_c base_cpp)
```

/my_project/utils/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(base_c)
add_subdirectory(base_cpp)

add_library(utils)
target_sources(utils PUBLIC common.h)
target_include_directories(utils INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

/my_project/utils/base_c/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(base_c base_c.c)
target_sources(base_c PUBLIC base_c.h)
target_include_directories(base_c INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

/my_project/utils/base_cpp/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(base_cpp base_cpp.cpp)
target_sources(base_cpp PUBLIC base_cpp.hpp)
target_include_directories(base_cpp INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(base_cpp base_c)
```

Answer (score 2):

`target_include_directories)` is what you are looking for, but not the `PRIVATE` option.

According to the 
[target_include_directories() documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html#command:target_include_directories) the `PRIVATE` option is for directories only used in that target, `INTERFACE` is for directories only used by dependent targets and `PUBLIC` is for both.

I suggest using in /my_project/utils/base_c/CMakeLists.txt

```
target_include_directories(base_c INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

This way you "link" the include directory to the target it belongs to and all targets dependent on it automatically include the directory.

Additionally you might want to move your public headers to their own subfolder `/my_project/utils/base_c/base_c/` and then include them as `#include "base_c/base_c.h"`. This introduces kind of a "namespace" to headers, preventing headers with the same name from different projects from beeing ambigous.

Comment: Do I need to do anything on the consuming side in `base_cpp`? Currently `find_library` returns `BASEC-NOTFOUND`

Comment: you dont need find_library in the same project. just use `target_link_libraries(base_cpp base_c)`

Comment: Ok, I did that, but it can't resolve the headers. Maybe I need `target_include_directories(base_cpp <something>)`?

Comment: @voddan: `it can't resolve the headers.` - Looks like your code includes headers in unexpected manner. Update your question post with new CMake code and actual error message.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but the explanation is off, so I didn't get it when I needed it :(